# Some questions about Google Fusion Table and Google Maps

Tags: google-fusion-tables, bigdata

we've a 10 million rows table that we want to upload to google fusion tables, it's possible that? we need to create different sheets I suppose? 
Every row has a latitude,longitude. Is possible to show on a map all this? 
we want the map group points depending on the zoom.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limitations stated on this Google Fusion Tables help page and the Maps Developer API, it's not possible to put 10 million features (locations) on a single map all at once - only the first 100,000 will load.

With that being said, I see nothing about how many rows you can have in your table; only a 5,000 column limit (recommended 100 columns or less for performance issues) and a 1 million character per cell limit.

https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/171181?hl=en

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer#overview

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response (sorry for the delay in answer!), it's right, only the first 100k are loaded.. I've done a test, oh! a pitty, how can "attack" this work? we want to do something like zillow.com, when more zoom is done to the map, more markers appear. If we've the max zoom, we can see a marker in every house of the viewport, some idea? :) thanks again!